# How to automatically set language preferences in Laravel each time a user visits?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to utilize the localization feature in Laravel for my web app. Here's my pseudocode:

```
If !session::has(lang)
  Get user's location and set proper language in session
App::setLocale(session::get(lang))
```

This code may not be perfect, but my main concern is where to put this code so that it will automatically run each time the user visits.

I want to properly centralize the code in one place and don't want to put the code in the wrong place. I could place it in route.php, make a service provide, or utilize a middleware. However, I want to learn the proper practice, any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest creating a [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#defining-middleware) and then [registering](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#registering-middleware) it as a global middleware by appending it to the `$middleware` array in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class.

Global middleware is called for every request automatically, so it seems like a good fit for your situation.